# If B is a Borel set in R then B×{0} is a Borel set in the plane.

Tags: measure-theory

I think I know how to prove the contrary implication looking at this answer [If $B\times \{0\}$ is a Borel set in the plane, then $B$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365662/if-b-times-0-is-a-borel-set-in-the-plane-then-b-is-a-borel-set-in-mat) But how would you prove that if B is a Borel set in R then B×{0} is a Borel set in the plane?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ defined by $f(x,y)=x$ is continuous and therefore measurable. We conclude the preimage of $B$ is a measurable set.

Therefore $B\times \mathbb R$ is borel-measurable. Now intersect it with the x-axis which is clearly also borel-mesurable and we are done.

Comment: So in order to prove that $\mathcal{B} \times \{0\}$ is a Borel set you say its clear that $\mathbb{R} \times \{ 0\}$ is a Borel set?

Comment: Well yes, its a closed set.

Comment: okay your right. Nice solution.